# How to connect a Glue notebook to an internal VPC service

Tags: aws-glue, aws-security-group

I have brought up a glue notebook that i would like to call a API service that is fronted by an AWS LB.

the notebook has a glue NETWORK connection to the internal VPC subnet.
The connection has a SG that has a all tcp ingress egress rules and a self referencing security group to all ports
The load balancer sg has a rule to allow all HTTPS from the cidr of the VPC and has also got a self referencing security group to all ports

But when trying to query the LB i get a time out error.

```
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7ff13c2199d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))
```